# flickering fix for iOS Phonegap causing scroll issue

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I used below code to remove blinking in my code for iOS Phonegap app:

```
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page, .ui-mobile [data-role="page"],
.ui-mobile [data-role="dialog"], .ui-page, .ui-mobile .ui-page-active {
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Environment:

iOS5.0
Cordova 2.0
Jquery 1.7.2
Jquery mobile 1.1.1

After usage of above code , scroll is not working in my app.
If I remove overflow:hidden in above code then I am getting flickering issue.

How can I solve scroll issue in my app